# Hello world in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, http, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there a way to implement logic similar to this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return "Hello, world!";
});
```

in **Rails** application? So the request `GET 127.0.0.1/` would just return a plain text **"Hello, world!"**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, create a new Ruby on Rails application.

Add this to your `config/routes.rb`:

```
root to: 'home#index'
```

And create an `app/controllers/home_controller.rb` like this:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render plain: 'Hello, world!'
  end 
end
```